# Laravel. Передать переменную из шаблона в контроллер

Tags: laravel, view, controller

в шаблоне вызываю метод:

```
@if($worldCup->rounds->count() == 0)
<a type="button" style="margin-right: 3px;" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{{action('WorldCupsController@resort_stage_1'  ,$worldCup->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-connectdevelop"></i> Shuffle</a>
```

Но в контроллере:

```
public function resort_stage_1(WorldCup $worldCup)
    {
        $worldCup->load('teams');
        return view('wc.admin.resort_stage_1',compact('worldCup'));
    }
```

переменная $worldcup пустая, а не из шаблона. Почему не передает переменную в контроллер?

В файле routes:

```
Route::get( 'wc/{worldCups}/resort_stage_1',              
          ['as' => 'admin.wc.resort.get',         
          'uses' =>  'WorldCupsController@resort_stage_1']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имя переменной и параметра вроде как должно совпадать чтобы каст сработал.

```
Route::get('wc/{worldCup}/resort_stage_1','WorldCupsController@resort_stage_1')
    ->name('admin.wc.resort.get');
```

[Route Model Binding Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding)

Answer (score 0):

Не прописал `$router->model('worldCup', 'App\WorldCup');`в `RouteServiceProvider.php`